# Apache redirect for multiple domains

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a series of domains like:

```
payroll.olddomain.com
billing.olddomain.com
support.olddomain.com
etc...
```

I need to redirect all of them to:

```
payroll.newdomain.com
billing.newdomain.com
support.newdomain.com
...
```

I could approach this in brute force fashion with a series of virtual host paragraphs, one paragraph per domain, as in:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName payroll.olddomain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://payroll.newdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
...
```

Or I could use a series of rewrites, one per domain, as in:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "payroll.olddomain.com" [NC]
RewriteRule .  "payroll.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}" [L,R=301]
...
```

But what I would *really* like to do, if possible, is find a simple and elegant way to (pseudo-code):

```
redirect <anything>.olddomain.com to <anything>.newdomain.com
```

I would assume a solution would include a `regexp` thingy, something like (more pseudo):

```
redirect (.*)\.olddomain\.com to http://$1.newdomain.com
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Place this in your root .htaccess file. Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

```
RewriteEngine On #Don't use twice.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That is brilliant, thanks! I was not aware that a captured pattern "(.+?)" from the RewriteCond could be referenced within a subsequent RewriteRule. It works perfectly. I did read the docs, but this capability was not clear. That is really powerful. Thanks again!